# Login with CryptoAPI on a USB Token

Tags: authentication, cryptoapi, e-token

Is there a way to login on a usb toke (iKey 4000) using CryptoAPI ? (Juts ot be clear, it's not about login with the token but on it) I know I can do that using Pkcs11. I need that in order to avoid the login dialog that is shown by the authentication client provided at the first operation that access the token.

Thanks in advance,
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

Can This token be used with CryptoAPI (Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider) ? If no, the "smart card minidriver" is missing for this token and you are not able to deal anything with them through CryptoAPI.

Otherwise, you need to acquire context of any key container on this token and use `CryptSetProvParam` function with parameter `PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN` or `PP_SIGNATURE_PIN`.

Note, that logging into the smart card or token in one application may not lead to "logged in" state for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Well, trying to address your issues:

No idea if It can be used with Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider, and there will be no other application using it, so it being stuck with this service is ok.

Your suggestion worked but I had to use PP_ADMIN_PIN instead of PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN or PP_SIGNATURE_PIN.

Thanks.